# TCP server takes wrong port number on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I am doing socket programming in C, and when i am starting my tcpserver on address INADDR_ANY and port no 2000, it starts well. But using command 'netstat -tulpn' , it shows the server is assigned port number `53255`. Clients are able to connect to this server when they connect using server port number `53255`, but get connection refusals when they try connect to port number '2000'.

Can somebody pls explain why the system is assigning the wrong port no to my tcpserver instead of one i am want to use which is 2000.

```
vm@vm:~/Documents/csepracticals/webserver/TCPWebserver$ netstat -tulpn
...
...
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53255           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16291/webserver`


server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = SERVER_PORT; /*#defined to 2000*/
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
bind(master_sock_tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Comment: I'm certain the answer lies somewhere in you code, which unfortunately you forgot to add to the question...

Comment: You need to specify the port in network byte order (i.e. use `htons(SERVER_PORT)`)

Comment: @Ctx, that worked...  :p

Comment: If it's 53255 every time, it isn't random. Be precise. It's wrong (by which I mean not as you expected), but it isn't random.

Comment: it was random , every time, it was being assigned a different port number also ...

Comment: Nonsense. That can only happen if you specified zero, and you didn't. Either it was random or it was 53255. Make up your mind.  Your question specifically states it was 53255, which is the byte-swap of 2000. Which is why the answer you accepted works.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I tried different port numbers and it gave the byte swap of those, so i thought it is generating port numbers as random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `htons(SERVER_PORT)` instead of `SERVER_PORT`